# How do I get back to the top of a while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

so I am trying to make a guessing game on my own and when the game ends I hope it will prompt the player if he wants to play again by typing yes or no like this:

```
Guess a number between 1 to 10: 7
YOU WON!!!!
Do you want to continue playing? (y/n) y
Guess a number between 1 to 10: 7
YOU WON!!!!
Do you want to continue playing? (y/n) n
Thank you for playing!
```

I managed to get the game working but I can't play the game again. I am stuck here:

```
guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
while True:
    if guess > num:
        print("Too high, try again!")
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
    elif guess < num:
        print("Too low, try again!")
        guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
    else:
        print("You guessed it! You won!")
        replay = input("Do you want to continue playing? (y/n) ")
        if replay == "y":
            **what to insert here???**
        else:
            break
```

I don't know what to type inside the if statement that will return my code to the top of the loop if the user press "y" and allows me to restart the game.

Any help will be appreciated! Please do not give me the entire solution but try to give me hints so I can solve this by myself! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the continue statement as it returns the control to the beginning of the while loop, in python.

Comment: Have you tried your suggestion with the code? Does the code now have the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two while loops. The first one to decide whether the player wants to play again or not and the second one is to get guess from the user until the user does the correct guess.

```
while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
    wantToPlay = False
    while True:
        if guess > num:
            print("Too high, try again!")
            guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
        elif guess < num:
            print("Too low, try again!")
            guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
        else:
            print("You guessed it! You won!")
            replay = input("Do you want to continue playing? (y/n) ")
            if replay == "y":
                wantToPlay = True
            else:
                break
    if wantToPlay == False:
        break
```

Comment: Quote from the question: "Please do not give me the entire solution but try to give me hints so I can solve this by myself". A `while True` look that does a conditional `break` as last statement can be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

To implement the game with the functionality to continue playing, I would recommend defining a function for the game and invoking this function recursively to initiate a new round. Here's an example approach:

```
def game():

  num = 7


  while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))
    if guess > num:
      print("Too high, try again!")
    elif guess < num:
      print("Too low, try again!")
    else:
      print("You guessed it! You won!")
      replay = input("Do you want to continue playing? (y/n) ")
      if replay == "y":
            game() # Restart the game for another round
      else:
        break
game()
```

Note that with this structure, the game function encapsulates the entire game logic, including the loop for repeated guessing and the option to replay. The while loop ensures that the user is continuously prompted to guess until the break condition is met.